# Justified Text in Classic Thesis CV Template

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm currently trying to put together a CV using the [classic thesis styled cv](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-styled-cv) template. I cannot seem to figure out how to get the text in each description to be fully justified. I've tried using the ragged2e package with the command \justify, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template defines `Description` to be `\raggedright`. Simply remove it and the text is justified.

```
\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}}
```

[image: dannyClassicThesisCv]